# Programmatically choose from which package to take a class

Tags: java, package

If I have two packages Px and Py with the same class C, is there a way to programmatically chose if I want to take C from Px or from Py?
Px and Py (or more packages) names are not known in advance either.

I have a lot of code where I use C, but I want the package from where I take it to be interchangeable.

Is there a clean way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using reflection. 
Use `Class<?> c = Class.forName("somepackage.SomeClass");` to get the class, and then you can choose the constructor you want and invoke it:

```
Constructor<?> ctor = c.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```

Answer (score 2):

A class `C` in two different packages are entirely different, so you cannot substitute one for the other, unless you:

1. Use an interface implemented by all versions of class `C`. *(recommended)*
2. Use reflection to access class `C`. *(not recommended)*

With an interface, the classes don't even have to have the same name.

*com/example/p/MyInterface.java*

```
package com.example.p;
public interface MyInterface {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

*com/example/px/C.java*

```
package com.example.px;
import com.example.p.MyInterface;
public class C implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // do something px related
    }
}
```

*com/example/py/C.java*

```
package com.example.py;
import com.example.p.MyInterface;
public class C implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // do something py related
    }
}
```

*com/example/py/MyOtherC.java*

```
package com.example.py;
import com.example.p.MyInterface;
public class MyOtherC implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // do something else py related
    }
}
```

You can now get an implementation of interface `MyInterface` by classname as a `String`:

```
String className = "com.example.py.MyOtherC";
MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface)Class.forName(className).newInstance();
myInterface.doSomething();
```